# Display students from table who belong to a school

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a list of schools I am displaying. In a dropdown for each school I want to only display students from student table whose fk is equal to pk in depart table. Depart Table is has fk school_schoolId. There are many schools. e.g. In student table - studentId=1, depart_departId=4, school_schoolId = 4. 
     In school table - schoolId=4
Therefore student 1 will be listed under school 4.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.School)
{
   @:<tr style="background-color:grey;-moz-border-radius: 15px;border-radius: 15px;">           
      <td class="accordion" style="width: 50%;padding-left: 10px;text-align: left;">
         <a href="#">@item.Name</a>
         <div style="font-size:10px;">
            @foreach (var student in Model.students)
            {         
               <div style="background-color:grey;width:100%;padding-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px">
                  <span style="margin-left:8%; text-align: center">@student.Name</span>
               </div>
            }
         </div>                                                                               
      </td>
   @:</tr>                                               
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code, it seems like the `Model` is not representing the data correctly.

In the first loop, you're looping through all the schools. This is good.

(I would change the name of the variable to `school` to better represent its role - just for the sake of clarity. I would also change the name of the `School` property to the plural `Schools` to represent that it's got a bunch of them.)

```cs
@foreach (var school in Model.Schools)
```

But in the second loop, which is nested inside the first, you're looping through all the students instead of just the current school's students.

A better approach would be to add a `Students` property to the `School` model class and then loop over the current school's students like so:

```cs
@foreach (var student in school.Students)
```

When you build the model in the `Controller` (or wherever you build it), make sure to add each school's students to the correct `Students` collection. Entity Framework is able to build up hierarchies like this for you if you configure it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.Where`:

```
@foreach (var student in Model.students.Where(s => s.SchoolId == item.SchoolId)) 
{

}
```

You could filter this out in your Model rather doing logic in the View.  Maybe something like `AvailableStudentsModel`.  You could also write an extension method on `Students` to determine if they are in that school which would be more efficient and make your code more readable.  You could then use it to populate the `AvailableStudentsModel` I mentioned.

Comment: While this is perfectly correct, it may well be better done when generating the model, as it meaans you can filter the records coming from the DB, rather than pulling everything and then filtering (depending on the type of students).

Comment: @Paddy - I just updated my answer as you typed the comment :)

Comment: Apoligies all, I have another table sitting inbetween these two tables.